# Generating scaffolding for existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

Newbie to RoR here. I have built models with no namespace. One of them is called 'Brand'. I then proceeded to use rails g "admin/brands" to put maintenance functionality under an admin namespace, using `rails generate scaffolding_controller "admin/brand"` - which produced the views and the controller. The unit tests fail when I rake test:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `admin_brands' for #<Admin::BrandsControllerTest:0x1034c0730>
test/functional/admin/brands_controller_test.rb:5:in `_callback_before_193'
```

in routes.rb I have:

```
# Administration routes
namespace :admin do
    resources :brands
end
```

The generated controller code is as follows:

```
class Admin::BrandsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /admin/brands
  # GET /admin/brands.json
  def index
    @admin_brands = Brand.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @admin_brands }
    end
  end

  # GET /admin/brands/1
  # GET /admin/brands/1.json
  def show
    @admin_brand = Brand.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @admin_brand }
    end
  end

  # GET /admin/brands/new
  # GET /admin/brands/new.json
  def new
    @admin_brand = Brand.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @admin_brand }
    end
  end

  # GET /admin/brands/1/edit
  def edit
    @admin_brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /admin/brands
  # POST /admin/brands.json
  def create
    @admin_brand = Brand.new(params[:admin_brand])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin_brand.save
        format.html { redirect_to @admin_brand, :notice => 'Brand was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @admin_brand, :status => :created, :location => @admin_brand }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @admin_brand.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /admin/brands/1
  # PUT /admin/brands/1.json
  def update
    @admin_brand = Brand.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin_brand.update_attributes(params[:admin_brand])
        format.html { redirect_to @admin_brand, :notice => 'Brand was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @admin_brand.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /admin/brands/1
  # DELETE /admin/brands/1.json
  def destroy
    @admin_brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
    @admin_brand.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_brands_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure how to debug this type of issue... I gather that paths are messed up somehow, but that is much as I can fathom at this point. Help appreciated.

Comment: Try `admin_brands_path` or `admin_brands_url` instead of just `admin_brands`.

Comment: First step of getting help is pasting the line that's giving you the error, ie `test/functional/admin/brands_controller_test.rb:5`.

Comment: Sure, I've posted the code that was generated. Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

In our company we dont use scaffold, especially when we need to generate admin namespace.
You can simply write admin namespace yourself.

## config/routes.rb

```
  namespace :admin do
      root :to => "base#index"
      resources :pages 
    # resources :states do
      # member do
        # get :make_default
      # end
    # end
  end
```

## app/controllers/admin/base_controller.rb

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_user!, :admin_user?


  layout "admin/admin"
  def index
    @page = Page.all
  end

private
  def admin_user?
   redirect_to root_path, :alert => 'This page is allowed for admin' unless current_user.admin
  end
end
```

## app/views/admin/base/index.html.haml

```
= link_to "New Post", new_admin_post_path
%ul
  - @post.each do |post|
    %li= post.title
```